# Is it possible to convert a 5 GHz connection from a non concurrent dual band router into a 2.4 GHz using another router?

Tags: router

What I need is to provide two connections, one in each band, the problem is that my current modem router is a non-concurrent dual band router, so that it can provide just one band at time (http://www.humaxdigital.com/gw/products/product.php?gid=524), and another problem is that my ISP requires me to use this modem router that they provided to me.

A solution to my case could be I buy a new router and connect via cable to the first one, and after that create a new connection in the 2.4 GHz band with this new router. Is this possible?

Here is the network diagram of my solution:
[image]

Comment: Hi Carlos, sadly home networking is off topic here, you should ask such  question on [superuser](http://superuser.com/), but all you need is a dual band access point and you can even disable the wifi on the ISP-supplied device.

Comment: OK, I'm going to make this same question there.
But when you say that I need a dual band access point it'd go where in my diagram? In place of the new router? I make a new diagram with your solution, can you confirm if I'm right?

Comment: Yes. This a very elaborate way to ask *can I add a 2.4G AP?*

Answer (score 1):

The JFL's solution:

[image]

Is this what you wanted to explain to me?

Comment: Yep that's right.

Comment: Thank you JFL, can you create a answer here pointing to the last diagram I created so that I can mark your answer as the solution, I don't want to mark my own answer as the solution because you were the genius here ;-)